# Threejs - changing opacity of loaded 3d object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a 3d object model loaded into a three.js scene like so:

```
var skull;

var loader2 = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

loader2.load(
    'skull.json', 
    function(object) {
        skull = object;
        scene.add(skull);
    }

);
```

How do i play around with the opacity of the model dynamically?
I've looked through the `skull` var but i cant find anything relating to opacity.

Any ideas how i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `skull` is a mesh (this depends on the contents of your JSON file), then it would be enough to alter `skull.material.opacity = 0.5`. Often, a 3D model file contains multiple objects, in which case you need to traverse it:

```
skull.traverse((node) => {
  if (node.isMesh) {
    node.material.opacity = 0.5;
  }
});
```

See docs for [THREE.Material](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/Material) and [THREE.Object3D](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D). three.js r91.

Comment: thanks. i found it within skull.children[2].material.opacity .

is there some way to hide the 'triangles' looking things in the opaque 3d object?

like so: https://imgur.com/a/elRij

Comment: That looks specific to your model... z-fighting? multiple objects? I think you'd need to create a JSFiddle or other demo showing the model and open a new question probably.

Comment: i wasnt referring to the brain, but rather the skull. but alright thanks again!